# Unable to include SFML header files in CLion project

Tags: c++, cmake, header-files, clion

I'm quite new to CMake and C++ in general, so today I've tried to import an external library like SFML to my project in Jetbrain's IDE CLion, but without any luck.

After spending a whole day learning about CMake in general and making SFML work with CMake in particular, I've finally managed my project's CMake to find the SFML library files.
However, when I approached a header file of my own to include a SFML header, I encountered a problem as it didn't find any headers from the library - And by that I mean the #include directives.
Since I am a newbie, I'm quite lost here.

Here's my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
# Set CMake's minimum required version
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)

#Set CMake's project name
project(testproj)

include_directories("${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")

#Set CMake's flags
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

#Set source files
set(SOURCE_FILES Animal.cpp Animal.hpp ConstantValues.hpp Enums.hpp Mamal.hpp Mammals/Lion.cpp Mammals/Lion.hpp)
add_library(testproj SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})

#Set CMake's module path to find the SFML Lib
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Modules/" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} "C:\\SFML\\SFML-2.3.2")

#Find the SFML lib
find_package(SFML 2 REQUIRED audio)
if (SFML_FOUND)
    include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(testproj ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
endif (SFML_FOUND)
```

It is worth noting that I'm working on Windows and I look only for the audio module in SFML.
What am I missing?

Comment: `I encountered a problem as it didn't find any headers from the library.` - What does this mean? `find_package` fails? Or `#include` directive fails? In the latter case, what exact error message is?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I've edited the post - I meant the #include directives. It doesn't give any special error message, just that there isn't such file or directory.

Comment: **Precise error message**, please. As `find_package(SFML)` doesn't return error, it works correctly. So, either SFML installation is broken, or you use incorrect `#include` directive.

Comment: @usr1234567 Took a look at it but it's not the same as the related posts describes the problem in Linux, and it's quite different than mine.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I've managed to solve the issue, please take a look at the answer I've added.

Answer (score 2):

OK So I've managed to pull to this off thanks to @Tsyvarev's help.
When I realized that the problem is related only to the #include directives and not the CMake script, I took a bit deeper look in it and found out that opposed to SFML's official documentation, the header files for each module are located *under their matching directory*.

So for example to include a header file from the audio module, I should do this:

```
#include <SFML/Audio/sound.hpp>
```

The key here is to look in the SFML folder first, just as you would do with boost.