# undefined reference when building C++ project using SFML

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, sfml, clion

Yes, there are already some SO posts about this - However they didn't help me solve my issue.

A few days ago I've already posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38809049/unable-to-include-sfml-header-files-in-clion-project) related to SFML - My project couldn't include the header files, or at least I thought so. I've marked the question as answered because the project compiled well, but silly me didn't try to actually **Build** the project, which involves the linking process.

The thing is I get the following error when trying to link:

> In function `AudioUtils::playSound(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
>   somepath: undefined reference to`__imp__ZN2sf11SoundBuffer12loadFromFileERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE'

It seems like the string class that's used in the SFML library is different than the one I use. If this problems occurs due to different compiler versions, then I can assure you that the version are the same.

It is also worth mentioning that I'm developing in CLion.

So what actually does cause this problem and how do we fix it?

Comment: Did you compile SFML yourself or did you download a version that was compiled using your compiler?

Comment: @nvoigt I've downloaded the latest version which was compiled against mingw-64

Comment: So are you using the same version of mingw-64?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes I am.

Comment: What is the content of the variable `SFML_LIBRARIES` when you execute cmake?

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Thanks everybody, I've solved the issue and posted an answer on it.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to resolve the issue - It was a pretty thin though foolish mistake:

I forgot to invalidate/reload CMake's cache, which led to the issue where the compiler versions aren't the same.